# Cypress run command without re-running test

Tags: console, google-chrome-devtools, cypress, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

Just wondering, say I have a lengthy cypress test that has finished running. Is there a way to try out a new cypress command, say something like

```
cy.get('.tg-tag').should('have.css', 'background-color', 'rgb(0, 128, 0)')
```

Thanks much!

Comment: As part of the same test suite? Just add it either to the end of your test, or create a new testcase for it. If you mean "separately from the existing test(s)", create a new file for it and then tell cypress to run only that file, specifically. If neither of those, or even if either of those: please [clarify that in your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to use a kind of interactive mode for new/additional commands, there's the experimental [Cypress Studio](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/cypress-studio) mode.

It's not free text, but you can add the expression you indicated, best described in the [PR](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/16295)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is the `cy.now()` internal command that allows the user to run a cypress command via dev tools in the test runner. Gleb has a general example [here](https://cypresstips.substack.com/p/cypress-secrets-cynow-and-cystate) and a more detailed example [here](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cy-now-and-state/). The Cypress docs has a small example [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging#Run-Cypress-command-outside-the-test).

There are also a few discussion on cypress github found below with examples of usage:

- [Support REPL #8195](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8195)
- [test commands in the Chrome DevTools console #6080](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6080)

You'll have to play around with your specific situation, but once your test has completed, open your dev tools and use the following format:

```
// cy.now(commandName, arguments…)

cy.now('visit', '/') // visit root
cy.now('contains', 'button', 'Sign in')
```