# How can I pause cypress test and try diff 'cy' commands like 'byebug' in ruby?

Tags: debugging, testing, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation

I'm writing my cypress tests in javascript in VS code.
Is there a way in to pause the test run and trial and error different things in terminal/console, something similar to "byebug" in ruby? changing in the code directly and rerunning takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically at the end of your test run or even during a pause, you can use `cy.now()` in your browser console. cy.now()'s first arg will be the name of the cypress command and the following args will be the cypress command arguments.

Here is a basic example.

```js
// test file
cy.pause()

// in browser console
cy.now('get', '.your-selector')
```

A more detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70858274/17917809).

Comment: I tried this but the console was giving the following error-
Uncaught ReferenceError: cy is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: Are you sure you are in the right js context in console?

Comment: i think that was the issue, it's sorted now. I've been trying this for some time now and looks like it doesn't work with all the commands, right?
Also, how do i perform an action on it like it yields a promise, what next?

Comment: I have only tried with a few basic commands like 'get' so I'm not sure. The yielded subject depends on your command so for the 'get' it would yield a DOM element.

Comment: it yields a promise(refer image in the link) https://imgur.com/a/1f1VI6c
now, how do i perform any action on this like click or type etc etc??

Comment: Ah, that is what you meant. Outside of using basic single cy commands, I am unsure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`cy.pause()`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/debugging#Step-through-test-commands) to enable stepping through functions in the test.

```js
it('some test', () => {
  cy.pause()
    .get('foo') // other commands
});
```