# How to interactively work with cypress $Chainer objects in the JS console?

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome-devtools, cypress, interactive

When running cypress e2e tests in browser I'd like to test and build up further cypress commands step by step. So I open the dev tools and [enter](/q/59800826) a cypress command in the JS console, but it always returns a `$Chainer` object. How can I make something useful out of that?

```js
res = cy.get('body')
>$Chainer {specWindow: Window, chainerId: 'ch-http://localhost:8080-200'}
// How can I access the dom element using res?

res = cy.get('body').should('exist')
>$Chainer {specWindow: Window, chainerId: 'ch-http://localhost:8080-201'}
// How can I see the result of should('exist')? 

res = cy.get('input[type=checkbox]')
>$Chainer {specWindow: Window, chainerId: 'ch-http://localhost:8080-202'}
// How to get the number of checkboxes from res?
```

This kind of cypress playground would be really useful. I tried [`Cypress.dom.unwrap`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/dom#Unwrap), but it has no effect on the `$Chainer` object. If used as shown in the docs but in the console, the callback inside then() is never called:

```js
cy.get('body').then(($el) => {
  // never called
  console.log($el)
  Cypress.dom.unwrap($el)
})
```

Can this be triggered somehow?

Comment: I think you are looking to use `cy.now()` in the browser console. Here is an answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70858274/17917809